# Div Title on div border how to

Tags: css, html

How can I place a text like below for a box title using Div.
Any CSS which I can use to place title of the div like in the example?

for example top border line of div with text will look

----Div Title---------

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <h1><span>Div title</span></h1>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
div{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

div h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -10px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

div h1 span{
    background-color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MeeW2/