# Div tag border with title

Tags: css, border

I need to display a border around a div tag with a title in the border itself.  In order to do this, this is what I have come up with so far

```css
.componentWrapper {
  border: solid cadetblue;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 95%;
}
    
.componentTitle {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

```html
 <div class='componentWraper'><p class='componentTitle'>This is the title</p>This is the component body text</div>
```

As you can see I am using margin property to push the title up on top of the border.  I am not sure if this is the proper approach to do this and I have the following questions.

1. I am positioning the title using pixels (margin) and a fixed value (-25px).  This is a site that has  to work on mobile phones, tablets as well.  Is this an acceptable approach?
2. I am setting the background-color to white so that the border does not appear behind the text, is this an ok approach?
3. Is there a better and more acceptable way to do this, I do not want to use fieldset because we have little control over the border (border-radius).

Comment: by the way, the CSS has 'componentWrapper' (double p) and the HTML has componentWraper (single p). You might want to fix that in your original code.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868267/div-title-on-div-border-how-to

Answer (score 6):

There are three logical ways you can use to achieve this.

1. You can use a `<fieldset>` with a `legend` which is the basic HTML way of doing this. You can find more information about this **[here.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset)**
2. Use custom CSS with positioning, not negative margins or etc.:

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

.componentWraper {
  margin: 40px; /* just for contrast */
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.componentWraper .componentTitle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='componentWraper'>
  <p class='componentTitle'>This is the title</p>This is the component body text</div>
```

3. Use custom CSS with **[pseudo-elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)**:

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

.componentWraper {
  margin: 40px; /* just for contrast */
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.componentWraper::before {
  content: 'This is the title';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class='componentWraper'>This is the component body text</div>
```

Comment: What the advantage of using top vs margin-top?  Plus will this change when I switch to a mobile phone?

Comment: Using positioning instead of misalignment is the better option since it will not affect relative elements causing further confusion.And yes, it will remain the same on mobile, you may have to tweak the width for some resolutions.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the "content: 'This is the title';" and have that be variable?  I have a lot of titled borders I want to use, and I don't want to have to copy the css for each one.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're on the right track. I'd make a few changes to have more control over the styling. You can use `ems` or `pixels`.

Wrap the title and content in a new div and give that a negative margin:

```
<div class='componentWrapper'>
  <div>
    <div class='componentTitle'>This is the title</div>
    <div class='componentContent'>
      <p>This is the component body text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

.componentWrapper div {
  margin-top: -1em;
}
```

Set your title to `display: inline-block` and use `padding` to control the white space around it (instead of using `width`)

```
.componentTitle {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/zZNLwP)

snippet:

```css
.componentWrapper {
  border: solid cadetblue;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.componentWrapper div {
  margin-top: -1.2em;
}

.componentTitle {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em .3em;
}
```

```html
<div class='componentWrapper'>
  <div>
    <div class='componentTitle'>This is the title</div>
    <div class='componentContent'>
      <p>This is the component body text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. I wanted to get rid of the negative margin, but couldn't figure out a way to do that.

See the Pen [offset title](http://codepen.io/vogelbeere/pen/xqgJbP/) by Yvonne Aburrow ([@vogelbeere](http://codepen.io/vogelbeere)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

**HTML**

```
<div class="componentWrapper">This is the component body text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.componentWrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 3em;
}

.componentWrapper:before {
  content: "this is the title";
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -29px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

I am not sure how a screen reader would deal with the title text being in the CSS (or how you would scale that up if you have a lot of different titles.